# Add a rubber duck to "discard" button

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, images, draft

At least on April 1st, and at least on programming-related sites, rubber duck should feature somewhere around the "discard" question.

[image: Ducky!]

We owe her.

Comment: Huh? I don't get it.

Comment: Why not ponies?

Comment: I'm relating to the concept of rubber ducky problem-solving.  Maybe it's not as well known as I thought, let me find you an explanation  :)

Comment: Rubber Ducks - Ducks are birds - birds fly - airplanes fly - so do dragons - dragons have scales - scales are played on musical instruments - instruments are also used in surgery - surgery is done by doctors - doctors wear scrubs - scrub is another word for erase - erase is to discard. Simples!

Comment: @BenLee I believe they are referring to the common phenomenom in programming which occurs when you explain your problem to someone else and realize what your issue is purely because you had to simplify the problem to describe it. In this case, taking the time to write a question acts as describing your question to someone else, and you may think of the answer as you right the question.

Comment: Oh. I'm well aware of [rubber duck problem solving](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html). I just didn't connect that to putting a rubber duck next to the discard button.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Did pony ever asnwer a question for you?  Yes, they giggle and glow in dark and other fun stuff, but AFAIK they don't solve programming-related questions...

Comment: @BenLee Ecxactly.  It happened to me countless times that in the elaboration of "good question" I ended up with no question at all.  That's when I want to say "thank you, ducky" and click the "discard" button

Comment: I guess I just don't connect rubber ducking to discarding at all. When I start to type a question and come to the solution while trying to compose it, I never click discard--I just close the browser window.

Comment: @BenLee Ah, I see.  So you have rubber ducky for "close window" button?

Comment: @BenLee - You. You... You just close the browser window??? Always click discard! Think about the poor lonely bits you leave behind you!

Comment: @Pekka웃 - low standards for April 1st, don't you think?

Comment: @Oded well, it can't be the *only* joke, of course. But it is kinda nice. I hope you guys will be the "pay for an answer" thing next year? That would be *so* cool

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I asked the expert. She said she works pro-bono.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a long time before April 1st.

Comment: A secret:  I *deliberately* left "Answer your own question" in the shot, silently admitting that alternatives may exist.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards 4/1 was just an idea, in fact I think that Rubber ducky would deserve **its own day** (I would be greatly complimented if it was "3 hours ago" (?!?) day.)

Comment: I couldn't really oppose this, but the concept looks bad. The rubber duck doesn't look like part of the button, it just looks randomly stuck there. I think it actually makes the UI more confusing.

Comment: @CodyGray 1. Make better design 2. Post it here 3. Rinse (duckies looove rinsing!) 4. Repeat

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards well it is now. ;-)

Comment: It does appear to have taken longer than I could have imagined @Shadow! Oded's comment is a little more brutal: _low standards for April 1st, don't you think"_

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards hard times for SE... Better than nothing... :) (and IMO better than last year's Dance Dance Authentication :-))

Answer (score 8):

This is done:

[image: A rubber duck asking, "Can I help?"]

See also: [Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck)

Comment: -1 this is different duck.

Comment: @ShadowWizard you probably forgot to downvote after posting a comment.

Comment: @alexolut no, just forgot my keys.