# Am I the only one for whom SO has became the rubber ducky?

Tags: discussion

Not seeking answers, just drawing attention to somewhat positive effect of StackOverflow I have noticed recently.

Today, for some fifth time in a row I didn't post a question I started typing. Once again I found my answer while halfway through.

The process goes like this:

- State my problems.
- State tools available for solving them that are at my disposal, and the constraints.
- State possible solutions and why they are not viable. Discuss why they are not viable; how each obstacle is insurmountable given accessible tools, constraints and my knowledge, or how standard solutions to them will not work.
- Find one with standard solutions that will work.
- Enjoy my solution, cancel posting the question and just proceed with my work.

Rubber ducky to be efficient must be believable. You must overcome the suspension of belief when explaining things to the ducky. You must believe the ducky can answer and help. A real rubber ducky doesn't really cut it for me, but SO works quite well!

Comment: Not seeking answers? So... what are we supposed to do with this post? Do you feel that it will assist future visitors? If so - how?

Comment: Also see: [What is the name for the psychological effect in which formulating a question answers that very question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48923), [Should we ask questions to "rubber duck" the solution?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60552), [How can I thank the community when I solve my own problems? (Rubber Duck)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74891), and [Add a rubber duck to "discard" button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189232)

Comment: You're not alone (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48923/what-is-the-name-for-the-psychological-effect-in-which-formulating-a-question-an, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20016/why-is-it-that-properly-formulating-your-question-for-stackoverflow-often-yiel?lq=1, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100772/do-you-frequently-find-the-answer-to-your-question-on-your-own-just-after-asking?lq=1, ...).

Comment: +1 because this happens to me *all the time*. In fact, about 2.5 years ago, [I asked this here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72822/do-you-find-that-when-you-go-to-ask-a-question-you-end-up-answering-one)