# Stack Exchange has been taken over by a rubber duck!

Tags: discussion, fun, april-fools, quack-overflow

I couldn't miss this now, on all SE sites:

> [image: quack]

What are the duck powers? Was anyone able to make it do or say anything other than "Quack"?

Comment: @Quant no kidding! See tags... :-D (i.e. I know what it is, just wondering if I missed any cool feature of it)

Comment: Best part is at the end ...

Comment: I enjoyed the part where random stuff turned up on my site unannounced, tried to gain access to my microphone and then was difficult to get rid of.

Comment: Oh joy. It also makes stupid noises. Great

Comment: when this features is introduced  ?

Comment: @Richard It doesn't actually use the microphone.

Comment: @READandSee-It'sNotaDupe - I know funny, and this isn't it

Comment: @Richard well, there is "I hate ducks" button...

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Didn't work for me (and apparently other people). I adblocked it in the end; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308570/how-do-i-turn-off-quack-exchange

Comment: The duck has definitely a bug. Even if I say that I do not have a microphone, it tries to listen.

Comment: why isn't there an official announcement?

Comment: @Paul It is not a bug. Read my answer.

Comment: @Ooker April 1 mate.

Comment: Where I am it is middle of the day 31 of March. Rather far away from 1 April.

Comment: I don't see it on the [Portuguese StackOverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: the joke is completely lost on me. How do i get rid of the f'n thing?

Comment: @george - You can either use adblock or wait until the unskippable animation and duck noises have stopped and click the "i hate ducks" button, then the close button

Comment: did that and its back. How many times to repeat the process?  Do you actually advise people to click through random pop ups?  Signing off all *.stackexchange (for quite a while).

Comment: @george Make sure you click "Goodbye, duck" at the end. Also, you have to accept cookies.

Comment: The duck is not on **all** SE sites. It seems our yellow rubber friend does not speak Russian, Portuguese, Japanese or Spanish.

Comment: Why did they put such a rude feature on the SE?  "Signing off all *.stackexchange (for quite a while)" Can't say that I blame them.

Comment: @Joe while I like it personally, I do wonder why you made it so hard to get rid of, and didn't provide any way to mute it. Is it too late to add such feature now?

Comment: I love the duck, I hope it sticks around beyond April Fools...

Comment: I hate the duck. I think that SO engineers could use their time fixing bugs and improving things instead of producing such useless annoying crap.

Comment: @VictorStafusa as you see from comments around here, some people do like it. It is nice funny distraction from the daily routine. It shows SE still got some humor and is not made of robots. Humor is healthy, and this one day a year is used to distribute humor all around the world. I bet it took few hours of a single dev time, not something that is nearly enough to fix even minor bug.

Comment: @Robotnik I don't know if it will stick around, but its wise words will `;)` : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging#In_popular_culture

Comment: @ADTC Oh I know what it's referencing ;)

Comment: Horribly unacceptable bug: clicking "I hate this duck" and then the duck rather than "Goodbye, duck" results in a crying duck floating forever in the lower right corner of screen, but only sometimes.

Comment: This is Easter duck..

Comment: The duc% suc&s. Sorry to say

Comment: I don't think rubber duck debugging is going to work [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWBYn.jpg)  More likely I will get [Anatidaephobia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F0b0.jpg).

Answer (score 53):

It is not exactly a **feature** but is a merely a *legend* (I don't have a better word). They basically want you to listen to your self twice and they believe that you will have your answer sometimes in the question itself. Go to [Confused Retriever](http://www.confusedretriever.com/) for more info.

[image: Ask]
**So why a rubber duck?**

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

> A rubber duck in use by a developer to aid code review In software
>   engineering, rubber duck debugging or rubber ducking is a method of
>   debugging code. The name is a reference to a story in the book The
>   Pragmatic Programmer in which a programmer would carry around a rubber
>   duck and debug their code by forcing themselves to explain it,
>   line-by-line, to the duck.

It does not matter if you have a mic or not. If you select "Yes" it will ask you to speak naturally but if you select "no" then this happens:

[image]

No matter if you say something out loud and clear it always gives the same output. It will ask you to speak louder and then do the silly "Quack" in the end.

[image: Quack]

**Quack Overflow says**,

> Whenever you’re stuck, rubber ducking is a powerful method for solving
>   even the most difficult problems. Insights are often found by simply
>   describing the problem aloud.

You can then either select the option "I have another problem", which repeats the same thing over again, or you could select the *"I hate this duck"* option, which will display the message below and a button with the text <kbd>Goodbye,duck</kbd>.

> The duck is sorry to hear that, but it understands.

[image: GoodBye]

**But don't do this. It makes her cry :(**

[image: Cry baby]

**When does this duck appear?**

I don't know. No matter how many times I hit refresh, go though questions or do anything it isn't coming back once I said "I hate this duck". :P

For really a technical point of view regarding this you can read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281271/4427870) answer.

**BUT again, you never know April 1.**

**How to get the duck back once you hated it?**

According to @Simon's comment and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308576/333344) answer I found out that a cookie is being stored once you hated the duck. Deleting the cookie gets the duck back.

[image: Cookie]

Comment: How to bring the duck back again after you've said that you hate it?

Comment: @SimonForsberg As I said in my answer I have no idea how to get it back once you hated it. But i tried logging in from another account and it is there.

Comment: [Nevermind, I found it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/308576/213556). Unfortunately I had to solve that problem myself as I had no duck to talk to.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Surprisingly I tried switching to an incognito window and the duck is back in the same account in that window. Also works with another browser as long as you don't hate it there as well. My guess is it's storing some `account+Browse`r combination on the machine on whereas to display the duck or not.

Comment: The duck is terrorizing me again. It's in the corner of my monitor at this very moment. It's creepy. I don't like jokes and I don't like April Fool's Day.

Comment: @Bread Just hate it once or twice and don't clear your cookies. You can always adblock it btw.

Comment: Do make a mention about the duck shedding a tear when you click "I hate this duck"

Comment: I did hate it once already (I'm afraid to go near it again, once is enough), and I rarely ever clear my cookies anyway. My adblocker is up and running as always. If the thing is harmless, I don't care, it's kind of funny and cute if that's the case. It has had me laughing a few times, if uneasily. The problem is that 'pretending' (?) to turn a mic on is creepy, and then the rude "quack" is really offensive. Also, adults don't talk to ducks :D If this is an April Fool's joke, I forgive you, but I really hope ya'll aren't serious with that thing. I don't do Cortana either, btw.

Comment: @Bread this thing is just a prank. And note that it doesn't even ask u for your mic permission. It is never listening. U can adblock it  manually. Right click and block.

Comment: Who wanna play duck duck goose..?

Comment: @Bread are you just afraid the ducks will eat you?

Comment: @NickT Im sure ducks are herbivores. :P

Comment: @Rishav I commonly see people feeding bread to the ducks and geese at a local pond.

Answer (score 4):

Some issues (problems?) get resolved by just being patient "a bit". Pretty sure this "duck" is related to [april-fools](/questions/tagged/april-fools) indeed (as per one of the tags you also used in your question). So it'll be interesting to see what will happen to it in about a day from now (the bets are open ...).

And even though SE sites appear to always enforce that any user around the world is operating from the same time zon (i.e. UTC, e.g. for review queue stats, rep rankings, etc), it might be that in this case this special feature is an exception to it. As it seems to have been activated around the time that April 1st started in the very first real timezone (somewhere in the Pacific?).

Comment: Timezone-sensitive stuff is traditionally buffered with +/- 24 hrs before & after. Was the case for previous years' April fools stuff, and every timezone-sensitive hat in any Winter Bash I've seen... nothing new here.

Comment: I never clicked on it, and therefore had no opportunity to "hate ducks" but it stopped appearing anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I spotted a little "duck" at the bottom right of my screen:

[image: Duck]

I clicked on it, and it asked me if I had a microphone:

[image: Ask the duck!]

I clicked "yes", and it then started listening to me:

[image: Quack Overflow is listening...]

I then whispered it a very personal question, and it had a bit of trouble listening to me:

[image: Speak up]

Eventually, it got through, and it responded with a loud...

[image: Quack!]

And left me with some wise advice:

[image: Advice]

Comment: Wait, you started posting this as a question and hit submit as answer by mistake? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not per se. I was typing this up as a question, but keeping careful watch to make sure no one beat me to posting it. You did, so I immediately copied it and posted it as an answer here

Comment: lol... so better remove the last sentence... :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Searchability

Comment: The duck behaves identically if you say you _don't_ have a microphone.

Comment: @DonaldDuck no that would be too radical change.

Comment: Why is this being downvoted all of a sudden?

Comment: @HenningMakholm If you click that you have a microphone, it says "Explain your problem out loud.", and if you click that you don't, it says "With the magic of the internet, you can just explain your problem anyway!".

Comment: @SonicWizard  - Perhaps non-programmers don't get the joke.

Comment: @Richard What joke? I'm a programmer.

Comment: @SonicWizard - The whole "rubber duck programming, explain it to a duck" thing is really only funny if you're a programmer. If you're not, it's just a duck that says weird stuff until you get rid of it.

Comment: @Richard Huh, never heard of that until now, as a programmer.

Comment: @SonicWizard - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Comment: @READandSee-It'sNotaDupe The OP of this question [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308564/stack-exchange-has-been-taken-over-by-a-rubber-duck/308567?noredirect=1#comment1005338_308567) he doesn't want it there. That said, now that it's in another answer, I removed it here.

Comment: Rubber ducking has never been seen as a joke for those who understand it.