# Can we please remove the review queues pop-up?

Tags: discussion, popups

Recently, there's been a pop-up about review queues:

[image]

It is extremely annoying, as I believe [other people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308570/how-do-i-disable-quack-overflow-i-hate-this-duck-button-is-only-temporary) [can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345938/lets-remove-the-get-updates-notification) [agree](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350976/can-we-please-clean-up-the-new-tooltips-around-the-upvote-downvote-buttons).  It does a lot more to distract and aggravate people than it does to inform them, and it acts against one of the keys to SE's success: a clean UI.

I for one do not want the site bugging me to death every other day, by covering things up and being distracting, about features that I will most likely never use - or about ones that are not new to me and that haven't changed.  This makes it harder and much more stressful to do things with the features that I do use, and many people feel the same way.

Can we please remove this immediately, and can we please avoid these sorts of "Got it" pop-ups in the future?  I don't remember ever meeting a user, here or in real life, who thought well of these things.

Comment: What should be the alternative? Clearly, they feel the need to inform users of new things, so, how should they do it better? personally... I'd rather this crap go into my inbox at the top right

Comment: The linked duplicate encourages feedback in the form of answers to it. I believe a request to remove this pop-up counts as feedback.

Comment: @Luuklag Why would you vote to close this as a duplicate of that post? This question is a request to have the feature removed.

Comment: @user1271772 The same thing has already been reported as an answer to the feedback post, and it's [OK to close such questions as duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330811/377214).

Comment: That post does not say it's okay to close such questions as duplicates: It has one answer with 5 negative votes and 9 positive votes saying what you want it to say, but the question is closed and not accepting more answers. Also, the same thing does not seem to have been reported as an answer to the feedback post (that's probably also why you didn't provide a link to the answer, because such answer doesn't exist).

Comment: @user1271772 [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363504/377214) is the one reporting it.

Comment: Reporting what? **This question is asking to have the feature removed entirely. The answer you pointed to is reporting a bug.**

Comment: @user1271772 as this is better posted as an answer there. That way all the feedbck regarding the new feature is in one place.

Comment: @Luuklag But it's not a duplicate. Also, while I disagree with this particular feature request, I do think the user deserves a fair chance at getting feedback on whether or not the community agrees with removing the pop-ups. Having them answer the question you suggested, will not give them that fair opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

For people that are annoyed by the fact that the pop-up shows up on every single site rather than just on the first site where you enter the review queue, there is a [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) tag on that complaint [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363504/391772).

As for removing the pop-ups *entirely*, while I share your sentiment for some of the pop-ups such as [the pop-ups for cookies described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362697/391772),  I have not found the new review queue pop-ups to be *overly* annoying (apart from them coming up on every site rather than just one).  They were a surprise to me, but once I read them once, and clicked "dismiss", they are gone (at least for the site in question).

I don't think I agree with your feature request to remove the review queue pop-ups altogether, but I do agree that they should only be on one site rather than on every site (and that's something for which a fix seems to be [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)).

Comment: Part of the problem is that if this isn't headed off now, it'll be a new pop-up next week, and another pop-up the week after, and so on.  And sometimes when you visit a different Stack, the same pop-up may have to be dismissed again.

Comment: @Panzercrisis I feel your pain because I don't like the cookie pop-ups, but if you haven't noticed: your question has received 4 close votes and 2 downvotes (none from me). Your feature request is not going to last long before the 5th close vote, and if you've looked at the thread where the feature was first announced, it just takes a few seconds of looking at the initial post, to see that SE will not be entertaining your request for them to throw away all of the hard work they put into getting these review-queue pop-ups started. Maybe you should post a question about the more general problem.

Comment: Agreed. They contribute to the discoverability of Stack Exchange features.

Comment: A bit ambiguous in your text: "but once I read them once and clicked "dismiss". If my testing is correct that does not mean you have the follow the ''more info* links. Just clicking the top right x in the popup, without reading anything, is enough to make them go away. So that's one click per site.