# Can we please stop adding notifications you have to dismiss on every single site separately?

Tags: feature-request, notifications

There's a new notification about review queues that was added a few days ago. I think it is a good idea in general to remind users that the review queues exist. Every notification is a slight annoyance, but I think this one is a reasonable one on paper.

But the actual implementation isn't reasonable, it's simply annoying for anyone using more than one SE site. The notification can be dismissed, but that dismissal isn't remembered network-wide, you have to dismiss it on every single site separately. I use several SE sites actively, and I also tend to occasionally browse the hot network questions for interesting or diverting content. Having to dismiss the same notification that often is just tedious.

This isn't the first time a global notification that has to be dismissed per site was added. It also isn't the second or third time, this happens every single time SE adds something like this. Sometimes when we complain enough a network-wide option is added later, but never from the start. I know this isn't as simple technically as might appear, but it is possible. I don't think it is an unreasonable burden to include the work necessary for a proper network-wide dismissal for every kind of global notification SE adds. And if it appears too much effort to do that, is that notification really that important that you need to show it to everyone?

Please just make dismissing notifications, popups and anything else like this always network-wide, and not just add this option after we complain on meta again. I'm just tired of complaining about this issue again and again.

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard I'm not complaining about the review notification specifically, but about all new notifications. This is not an exact duplicate, my post is about not adding new notifications without global dismissal, the suggested duplicate is about retroactively fixing this for the review notification (which is exactly what I complain about here, that SE only fixes later this when enough people complain)

Comment: Worth to mention, [requested already for the new review notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363539/152859).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we please remove the review queues pop-up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363518/can-we-please-remove-the-review-queues-pop-up)

Comment: To close voters: this is a *general* request for *all* types of popups, not just for the review queue pop-up. The author here is asking that such popups not be deployed in the future for *any* type of notification. @Rob Not a duplicate.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I'm not asking that they don't use popups, I'm only asking that for every dismissable popup or notification the dismissal should always be remembered network-wide

Comment: @MadScientist re-reading the title, it's not really clear. It does say "stop adding notifications". I've been thinking to edit into something like "Please have notifications only when they can be globally dismissed", but not sure enough it's better so didn't do it. For you to decide.

Comment: Related comment: [Yaakov says it's an expensive lookup without a non-trivial rework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345661/the-follow-questions-and-answers-feature-is-now-live-across-the-network/345674#comment1158070_345674). Perhaps that non-trivial rework should be high on the agenda if SE plans to do more of these popups.

Comment: Somehow the system manages to show my profile picture and current reputation and badges at the top of the site for every site I visit without it being a huge performance problem. I'm not saying it would be easy to design a solution or trivial to implement, but it doesn't look impossible to do to me (who admittedly is not a web app programmer). I don't have to log into each site individually, and I get inbox notifications across all sites, so there is some information that is persisted while I'm logged into the network isn't there?