# How do I reenable Quack Overflow if I disabled it?

Tags: support, april-fools, quack-overflow

I accidentally disabled Quack Overflow after asking it one question. How do I reenable it?

Comment: Happy Easter.. Bunny goes Duck comes..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Check your cookies

The duck saves a `quack` in your cookies. Open your browser's cookie collection and remove the `quack` cookie for the site where you want to re-enable Quack Overflow.

For example in Firefox, right click on an empty part of the page, choose "information", then "security" and "show cookies". There should be a `quack` cookie with its value set to `1` for the sites where you disabled Quack Overflow. If you remove `quack`, Quack Overflow gets re-enabled.

## Bookmarklet / code

If you don't want to check your cookies manually, you can also run the following code in your browser's console:

```
$.cookie("quack",null,{"path":"/","expires":3})
```

This will unset the `quack` cookie. Here's a [bookmarklet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet):

```
javascript:$.cookie("quack",null,{"path":"/","expires":3})
```

Note that you will need to refresh the page afterwards.

## References

Please take care when you follow the following guides, as wrong usage may make the Cookie Monster cry.

- Firefox: [Delete cookies to remove the information websites have stored on your computer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-cookies-remove-info-websites-stored)
- Chrome: [Clear, enable, and manage cookies in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- Internet Explorer 6: [Internet Explorer 6 (Win) - Clearing Cache and Cookies](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=12315)

Comment: Cookies. It is always cookies.  

Comment: ...I didn't have to do anything more than load this page _and it has returned_...  wait a second, the setting is particular to the community because it is not back on SO

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, so you can say, "but I gave you cookies" to them

Answer (score 11):

### Deleting the `quack=1` cookie in Chrome

1. Open the developer tools

   - Menu ⮕ More tools ⮕ Developer tools
2. Select the "Application" tab.
3. Expand the "Cookies" item on the left, and select the Stack Exchange domain you're using.
4. Enter "`quack`" in the filter/search box.
5. Click on the entry that remains in the list to select it.
6. Press the "X" (Delete Selected) button to remove it.
7. Reload the page.
8. [image]

[image]

Comment: Is that a hand drawn duck..?